# Как передать параметры в скрипт по именам?

Tags: bash, linux

То есть если есть некий скрипт с параметрами apple и orange

```
script --apple yes --orange no
```

или сокращенно a и o

```
script -a yes -o no
```

Или еще что-то такое, не использующее %1, %2 и т.п.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[getopt](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ru/library/au-unix-getopt/) Вам поможет.

Я все таки умудрился указать неправильную ссылку. Это ссылка на getopt для Си. А поскольку вопрос был про скрипт, да и в метках указан bash, то полезней будет все же посмотреть [здесь](http://citforum.ru/operating_systems/manpages/GETOPT.1.shtml).

В принципе аналог getopt можно найти в любом языке для Unix.